# Is downloading a massive table to ADLS through DataBricks just to join it to a smaller table inefficient?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse

Let me know if this question is ambiguous and I can provide more details. My DataBricks environment is attached to an Azure Synapse instance. We have a large amount of ADLS storage. The first part of our PySpark script creates two dataframes from SQL queries that will be run on different servers. One of those dataframes is small (think like 30,000 records) and the other is large (think like 1 billion records). We inner join the two dataframes on "ID" (just an example column name) and the rest of the script only uses the results of the join, which in this case always has 30,000 records or less. We're essentially using the join as a filter here for the larger table. I feel that pulling in the entire larger table just to filter it down must be pretty inefficient. Is there a better way to do this in DataBricks using PySpark?

I would just upload the smaller table to the server that holds the larger table, but we have security limitations that prevent us from doing that.

Comment: You will have to pull down the whole table if the small table act as a filter to filter the large table. Think about it this, how else would you know all the correct rows of large table have been selected without going through each row? You can look into broadcasting the smaller table in the join function so that the join is efficient.  Example here https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/broadcast-join-in-spark/

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using either of below strategies.

1. **Broadcasting the smaller Table:** If one of your dataframes (in this case, the smaller one) can fit in memory, consider broadcasting it to all worker nodes. Broadcasting avoids shuffling data across the network, which can significantly speed up the join operation.

> from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
>
> broadcast_small_df = broadcast(small_df) result_df = large_df.join(broadcast_small_df,
> on="ID", how="inner")

2. **Repartitining the Large Table:** If the larger table is too big to be broadcasted, consider repartitioning it based on the join column (in your case, “ID”). This ensures that rows with the same “ID” are colocated in the same partition.

> num_partitions = 100  # Adjust as needed
>
> repartitioned_large_df =
> large_df.repartition(num_partitions, "ID") result_df =
> repartitioned_large_df.join(small_df, on="ID", how="inner")